# How to log text message in case of successful web requests using ELMAH and C#

Tags: elmah.mvc

Can anyone help me to know regarding how to log custom message using ELMAH and C# ,in case of successful web requests return status code 200.

Is there any method similar to the one as mentioned below :

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
```

to log custom message.

A code sample would be very useful.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, ELMAH only handles exceptions (Error Logging Modules and Handlers), but with this little trick you can make it log whatever you want, whenever you want

Note that this may not be the only or best approach to solve your problem

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new NotImplementedException("blah blah blah whatever you want")); //ELMAH Signaling
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me but can you please let me know is there any way to replace the code : new NotImplementedException with some custom class which may help me to distinguish from other type exceptions that are occurring.

Comment: Hi! you can use a custom class IF it is inherited from the Exception class, so it would be some kind of exception as well, this link may help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/90646/Custom-exceptions-in-C-NET

Comment: Good luck, and if somebody has a better way to do this, please tell us! (i also need it!) 
I really like ELMAH and i use it in all my ASP.NET websites, it also works fine in  webservices projects.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this rather late to the party, but I came across this article wanting to post some "non-exception" information with Elmah as well.

I started with creating a new `Exception` object with a custom name and that name would be in the `Type` field in my database but that was not exactly what I wanted.  I then noticed that Elmah wants an `Error` object.  And that the `Type` field was `{ get; set; }` so I had my answer.

I created a static helper class to make it less code each time I needed it:

```
public static class ElmahTools {

  public static Error LogHangFireInfo(string message) {
    var Result = new Error(new Exception(message));

    Result.Type = "Hangfire Info";

    return Result;
  }
}
```

At the top of the Class where I want to log information, I added the following:

```
private static readonly Elmah.ErrorLog ErrorRepo = Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null);
```

Then in my code, where I want to actually log info, I have the following:

```
ErrorRepo.Log(ElmahTools.LogHangFireInfo($"Job: {context.BackgroundJob?.Id} state has changed from {context.OldStateName} to {context.NewState.Name}"));
```

I initially was just going to do:

```
new Error { Type = "My Custom Info", Message = "Some message" };
```

But that failed because the `TimeUtc` was not filled in.  So I simply just create a rather empty `Error` with the message and change just what I need to after (e.g. `Type`.)

Hope this helps someone.